# How can I convert my one of my data columns from character to integer in R?

Tags: r, number-formatting, na, coercion

I need to convert one of the columns in my data frame from character into numeric, however, when I apply this

`data_frame$column_name <-as.numeric(as.character(data_frame$column_name))`

It outputs the Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion and most of my data is replaced by NA.

Could anyone help me as to how I can convert the column from characters to numeric, without most of my data being lost?

I am new to R and would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: you need to share us your dataframe structure.

Comment: @zohge can you check the class of that column by running 'class(data_frame$column_name)' in your console? Sometimes class conversion issues cause NAs.

Comment: Also it could be because your column contains spaces " " or the number contains comma "10, 000" both of these would cause it to give this error. As Statistic said it is best to share a sample of your dataframe.

Comment: If you do: `data_frame$column_name_str <-as.numeric(as.character(data_frame$column_name))` and then `subset(data_frame, is.na(data_frame$column_name_str)` you should get a hint, which items are causing the trouble.

Comment: @NaremanDarwish Yes that was my problem! Just fixed it thanks!